# Strip out ad from html string

Tags: php, regex

I have a variable containing html string.  This string has this particular code

```
<a href="http://www.pheedo.com/click.phdo?s=xxxxxxxx&amp;p=1"><img border="0" src="http://www.pheedo.com/img.phdo?s=xxxxxxxxxx&amp;p=1" style="border: 0pt none ;" alt=""/></a>
```

Using regex, how can I remove that.  Basically looking for the pheedo.com domain, and stripping out the link and image tag.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not exactly sure which part of the string you try to extract. "www.foobar.com"?

Comment: He's extracting the anchor tag and the child image tag when the domain matches pheedo.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should match the tags (written in PHP):

```
$regex = "#<a href=\"http:\/\/www\.pheedo\.com[^>]+><img[^>]+><\/a>#"
```

Comment: There is no need to escape quotes or forward slashes in regex. This is always a requirement of the host language, and should not be included without the correct context.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.  This worked well with PHP, which I should have stated, is what I was after.

Answer (score 2):

This is an anti-answer: Don't manipulate arbitrary HTML with regexes! HTML is a really complicated spec, parsing it properly can be a nightmare.

Use a library like [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) or the built-in [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/dom), they know how to deal with all the weirdnesses of HTML for you.

Answer (score 1):

For a more generalized approach, (text/html ads, different urls on the same domain, etc...) you could try

```
<a.*href="[^"]*pheedo.com[^"]*".*</a>
```

Just replace any matches you find.  Keep in mind that if there is a child `<a/>`, you're going to have problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $text = '<a href="http://www.pheedo.com/click.phdo?s=xxxxxxxx&amp;p=1"><img border="0" src="http://www.pheedo.com/img.phdo?s=xxxxxxxxxx&amp;p=1" style="border: 0pt none ;" alt=""/></a>';
    $reg = "/href=\"(http:\/\/\S+?)\"/i";
    preg_match_all($reg, $text, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

    // $matches[1] should now hold all the domain name "www.pheeedo.com"
```

I did it this way so you could pass a page to the preg and get all the matching results in an array.../

I did some simular stuff to make this image search tool if you are interested.

http://www.iansimpsonarchitects.com/fraser

You can view the full PHP source from a link on the page.

F.